# Cursor placement with CSS styled image Text input boxes

Tags: css, xhtml

I Have a styled search box which uses a background, whenever I click on the box the cursor flashes larger than the text box, until I type where it appears at the correct size.

This is the HTML -

```
<div class="row2 zero_padMarg floatRight">
 <label for="srcTxt" title="search form">search</label>
 <input type="text" id="srchCom" name="srcTxt" class="validate[required,length[3,75]] text-input txtBox">
 <input type="submit" class="searchSubBtn" value="submit" title="submit search" name="submit">
</div>
```

```css
.searchBlock input#srchCom {
    background:url("../images/srchSml.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
    border-style:none;
    font-size:11px;
    height:23px;
    line-height:normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:24px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:160px;
}
```

Any ideas on a cross browser solution please?

Thanks for your help
Paul

Comment: Interesting. In Firefox 3, it looks like the caret height for the empty input box is set to the height of the input box (set `height: 100px;` and you'll see that initial cursor get a lot bigger...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try using padding to suggest that the content height is the same as the font-size. Add:

```
padding: 6px 0;
```

...and reduce the overall height to the same height as the font-size:

```
height: 11px;
```

This looks to me like a Firefox bug.

Comment: thanks Matt, the large cursor still appears on first click though.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, forgot to mention the important bit: you'll also need to reduce the height of the input to match the text height. Updated answer. This makes the height of the textbox match the height of the text, thus making the cursor the right size, while retaining the overall height of the box, which should allow the background image to be shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you change your `<input>`'s height?

Comment: thanks, that would reduce the size of the background image aswell as the cursor though.

Comment: As Matt said add a padding to keep same height reducing "height" value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I tried removing height of the text box and gave appropriate padding for top and bottom, it worked very well for both IE and firefox.